# ReactiveSearch is requiring vue.js as a dependency and no longer working because of it

Tags: reactjs, reactivesearch

I had reactive search working well. I pushed it to my dev branch and my CI wasn't complaining till yesterday.

Now I'm getting errors that ReactiveSearch is missing vue.js

When I look at the ReactiveSearch project, it appears that vue was added to reactiveCore recently.

I'm not sure installing vue is a great idea considering I'm running a react app. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

> ERROR in ./node_modules/vue-types/es/utils.js
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'vue' in
>   '/Users/ianseabock/stud-fbase/ui/node_modules/vue-types/es'
>   @ ./node_modules/vue-types/es/utils.js 2:0-22 214:4-7
>   @ ./node_modules/vue-types/es/index.js
>   @ ./node_modules/@appbaseio/reactivecore/lib/utils/vueTypes.js
>   @ ./node_modules/@appbaseio/reactivecore/lib/index.js
>   @
>   ./node_modules/@appbaseio/reactivesearch/lib/components/basic/ReactiveBase.js

Comment: What is contained in your js files? How is your project set up?

Comment: I think the reactivecore dependency might not be updated. Might be better to create an issue at the repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for filing the issue on Github. This has been resolved in the `6.0.3` release - https://github.com/appbaseio/reactivecore/issues/20.